# jquery.keypad with jquery.masked input

Tags: jquery, maskedinput, numeric-keypad

I am trying to mask the input from the jquery.keypad.js using the jquery.maskedinput.js plugin to mask into a date. But a simple textbox without keypad over it works fine.

But I am not able to do it.
html is:

```
<input type="text" id="defaultKeypad"/>
<input type="text" id="defaultKeypad2"/>
```

javascript is

```
$('#defaultKeypad').keypad();    
$("#defaultKeypad2").mask("99/99/9999");//this works
$("#defaultKeypad").mask("99/99/9999");//this doesn't work
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VvGLf/

Comment: So you want the keypad AND the mask??

Comment: Yes. I want both keypad and the mask.